# Mock a protected method which is part of a extended abstract class

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4, powermockito

**Class A**

```
public abstract class A{
  protected C _c = null;

  public A(){
  }

  public B(C c){
    _c=c;
  }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B extends A{

 public B(C c){
   super(c);
 }

 public String dosomething(){
   this._c.dosomethingelse();
   return String s;
 }

}
```

I am trying to unit test dosomething(). i am running in to an issue where as in this._c is null(Throws a null pointer exceptionat this line) i am new to mockito and unit testing not sure on how to make it skip that step so that it runs the other logic. i am using Mockito and PowerMockito

Comment: `public B(C c){
    _c=c;
  }` This does not compile in `A`.  What is your real code?

Comment: How did you create object of class B? did you pass in a valid object of C?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using spring-test

In your init try something like this :

```
//Create instance of C (or get already existing one)    
C myC = new C();
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this., "_c", myC);
```